# innerText of XmlNode from a String

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

Is there anyway I can create nodes out of a string? I've searched the Web looking for something, but couldn't find anything that works!

```
 string _configFileName = @"d:\junk\config.xml";
 XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmldoc.Load(_configFileName);

 string xmlTags = @"<queue name=queueName autoStart=true>
  <deleteFile>true</deleteFile>
  <impersonation enabled=true>
    <user>domain\username</user>
    <password encrypted="true">********</password>
  </impersonation>
  <tasks>
    <task>cp</task>
    <task>rm</task>
  </tasks>
  </queue>";
  queueParent.InnerText = str;//the Xml parent node of the new queue node that I want to add
   xmldoc.Save();//will write &lt;queue name= INSTEAD OF <queue name=
```

So the problem is having the special characters in XML "<" and ">" written into the file as "<" and ">". 
Your input is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the [`InnerXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.innerxml.aspx) property instead of `InnerText`.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("root");
        doc.AppendChild(root);
        root.InnerXml = "<child>Hi!</child>";
        doc.Save(Console.Out);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked fine. I tried it yesterday and didn't work. It was  a long day perhaps!

thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an XmlDocument from a string using xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlTags)

Comment: yeah, that's another option that works for me. I wanted something with less headache. but you have to use 
     someNode.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(rolesNode,true ));
to add it to the first DOM-tree as you are building a new DOM-tree.